# Shortcut vs some other way for putting banner at start of function

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

If I have to put say something like `// ***********************` at the start of every function, how can I do in intellij where I define a macro or sth or some other way? 
I am using Goland

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GoLand then you can define a Live Template the same way you have in IntelliJ IDEA. Go to `Settings (Preferences on OSX) | Editor | Live Templates | Go` and add a new template with the format you need.